# How to change from onclick to time automated script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i downloaded a simple picture slider using jquery. But it seems the transition and the change of the picture only works when a certain link is clicked. I want to make it automatic and loops back at a certain looping time.

```
<a href="#" class="change_link" onclick="$('.slideshow').blinds_change(0)">1</a>
<a href="#" class="change_link" onclick="$('.slideshow').blinds_change(1)">2</a>
<a href="#" class="change_link" onclick="$('.slideshow').blinds_change(2)">3</a>
<a href="#" class="change_link" onclick="$('.slideshow').blinds_change(3)">4</a>
<a href="#" class="change_link" onclick="$('.slideshow').blinds_change(4)">5</a>
<a href="#" class="change_link" onclick="$('.slideshow').blinds_change(5)">6</a>
<a href="#" class="change_link" onclick="$('.slideshow').blinds_change(6)">7</a>
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Give more details. Slider name for eg.

Comment: http://www.littlewebthings.com/projects/blinds/

Comment: like for example the picture changes itself at a period of time. And when it gets to the last one, it goes back to the first link again. Since by default it only triggers when clicked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this:

```
<script>
    var pictureInterval = setInterval(function() {
        var i = 0;
        return function() {
            i = (i + 1) % 7;
            $('.slideshow').blinds_change(i);
        }
    }(), 3000);
</script>
```

It will move to the next picture every 3 seconds.

If you want to cancel this, use `clearInterval(pictureInterval)`;

Comment: hi, it got into the next picture, after it it doesn't go on the next one.

Comment: wait, what actually happened is that it went on the last picture, then it remained stuck there..

Comment: It was because a global `i` was already being used somewhere else. I put it in a closure. See edited answer. (I would have done this at first, since it is MUCH better this way, but it makes the answer a little harder to understand for some.)